# Path Not Found error when opening VB6 project from a shared folder on Virtual PC 2007 (XP sp3)

Tags: iis, vb6, windows-xp, virtual-pc

I currently work on a small software team that primarily maintains legacy software. I am trying to set up a Virtual PC that we can use to do this maintenance. Specifically, I would like to be able to debug and run VB6 web apps from a folder on the host PC. My constraints are as follows:

1. The Virtual PC will not be registered on the domain.
2. The server that hosts our Subversion repository does **not** run the subversion service so the only way to interact with the repository is through "file:\\", which requires domain authentication.
3. It is not possible to debug/run VB6 web apps that are located on mapped network drives, because IIS requires that the VirtualPC be on the same domain as the network drive
4. I would like to avoid having to copy the folder from the host pc to the VirtualPC and then copying it back in order to have the latest revision from Subversion

So, I am trying to use VirtualPC's shared folder feature to share the host machine's Subversion directory and open the project in VB6 on the VirtualPC. Problem is that Visual Basic throws the error: "Path not found: '\\C:\\Subversion\Path\Project.vbp'" when I try to open it. Folder C:\Subversion on the host machine is mapped to G: on the VirtualPC. If anyone can help me resolve this error or find some other way to accomplish this, I would be deeply grateful.

Oh, both host and virtual OS is Windows XP sp3. Using VB 6.0, IIS v5.1.

I can manipulate files in the shared directory freely from the VirtualPC ie. copy, paste, delete, etc.

Comment: So this error occurs when you try to open the project in the VB6 IDE? Is that the full error message? I take it the project does not open at all. Are you opening a project group (VBG) or a single project (VBP)?

Comment: Yes, that is the full error that occurs when the VB6 IDE tries to load the project. It is a single project that does not open at all.

Answer (score 0):

VBP and VBG files are text files. Look inside them and see whether C:\Subversion or C:\Subversion appear anywhere, perhaps for a subproject in a project group. If they do, change it to use relative paths rather than absolute paths.

Comment: I have searched through the project file and there are no references to c:\Subversion. All of the references have relative paths like ..\..\..\Program Files\XXX\foo.dll (or .tlb). Also, I can at least open the project when I have that same folder mapped as a network drive.